# A line not plotted

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Here, I am trying to get `TikZ` to plot the line y=x.  I get an error.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{mathtools,systeme,array}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,clip=false,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-7,xmax=17,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
ymin=-4,ymax=14,
restrict y to domain=-4:14,
enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
axis line style={latex-latex},
ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[dashed,samples=2,domain=-6:16]{x};
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: An error in general or some specific one in particular?

Comment: First, you need an \end{axis}.  And for some reason the restrict y to domain=-4:14 is causing problems.

Comment: @John Kormylo  I added `\end{axis}` right before the end of the environment for `TikZ`.  The only depiction I get is that of the axes.  Why isn't any part of the line y=x drawn?!

Comment: If you remove the "restrict y" etc. line it will work.  Or use restrict y to domain=-7:17.  I haven't a clue as to why.

Comment: @John Kormylo  I just realized the reason it wasn't plotting.  I only have two sample points for the line.  Since the domain for the x-axis was as small as -7 but the domain of the y-axis was only as small as -4, the first point on the graph y=x could not be plotted.  I edited the domain so that the minimum and maximum values were the same.

Comment: Also, if you use domain* it works like it should.

Comment: @John Kormylo  What does this option `domain*` allow?  I had not previously seen this command.  (Do you know the page in the pgfplots manual it is discussed?)

Comment: Just set the samples to a large number `samples=100` or eliminate that `samples=` option all together.  Also, you don't have `\end{axis}` in the MWE you posted.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `\end{axis}`. Once you add that your MWE compiles and produces:

[image]

No points are displayed as you have set `samples=2` and `domain=-6:16` but also have `restrict y to domain=-4:14`. Thus the two sample points, `x=-6` and `x=16` are not plotted as they are outside of the restriction you have placed on `y`.

Best solution is to eliminate `samples=2` or specify a larger number of `samples=`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{mathtools,systeme,array}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=4in, axis equal image, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-7, xmax=17,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-4, ymax=14,
    restrict y to domain=-4:14,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty}, ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=south west}
    ]
    \addplot[dashed,domain=-6:16, ultra thick, blue] {x};
    \end{axis}% <---- Was missing
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```